# How do you change default detach key sequence in docker?

Tags: docker

Docker container's detach key sequence by default is control+q or control+p.
There is an option to set key sequence when starting a container using `--detach-keys "<sequence>"` but I am looking for a permanent change.

Is there a way to change this key sequence to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per user, you can configure this in the `$HOME/.docker/config.json` file. Add a json entry similar to:

```
{
  "auths": { ... },
  "detachKeys": "ctrl-x,x"
}
```

The "auths" line is just giving a relative location in the json, ignore this if you don't have an existing logins stored in this file. See [this documentation](http://docs.master.dockerproject.org/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) for more details.