# AzerothCore Docker, can't detach after a 'docker-compose up'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

I'm using docker in a debian 9.
After the 'docker-compose up' command, I cannot detach. with 'ctrl+p' and 'ctrl+q' (accessing directly or via ssh ).
I can detach closing the ssh console, and open again to continue.
Using "docker attach" to run commands, ctrl+p and ctrl+q, work fine.

Can I detach after do an 'docker-compose up'?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your environment? Are you directly logged into debian? or do you use an ssh client like putty from a windows machine? This is a very common issue with docker in general. Sometimes it can be other program key bindings, or issue with the ssh client not passing it through to the server. Some suggest to just change the key binding. Here is one example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782538/how-do-you-change-default-detach-key-sequence-in-docker#:~:text=Docker%20container's%20detach%20key%20sequence,%2Bq%20or%20control%2Bp.)

Comment: But using "docker attach" this key binding work fine.
I try it directly into debian, and using putty in a windows 10.

Comment: You might want to try using ‘docker-compose up -d’ instead then. It should launch the docker containers in the background and you can then use the ‘docker attach’ command after.

Comment: Exactly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @locus313 said, the command ‘docker-compose up -d’ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Ctrl + Z" two times. It suspends current processes after "docker-compose up" and you get back to console. You might want to do "docker-compose down" and then "docker-compose up -d" after you got back to console just to be safe.

Comment: Hi, can you put relevant information, as a link to specific docs?